# How to Hide or Remove the Viewport in Stripe Dashboard for Backend-only Apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-apps

I am currently developing a Stripe app intending to make it available in the Stripe Apps Marketplace. This app is primarily a backend service, as the frontend will be a mobile application published on both Google Play and the App Store.

However, while working with the Stripe dashboard, I noticed the viewport that displays on the right side. Since my app does not have a frontend component that integrates directly with Stripe, I would like to hide or remove this viewport.

Is there a way to disable or hide the viewport for backend-only Stripe applications? Any guidance or documentation references would be much appreciated!

I've tried to remove all the `views` objects in the `stripe-app.json` file, but the app was stuck.